# Decreasing scale depending on touch movement speed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, touch, scale

## I want my object scale to decrease depending on touch movement speed.

Here's my script that didn't work:

```
if (Input.touchCount > 0 && canRub)
    {
        Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
        if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
        {
            scaleX -= transform.localScale.x / (strengthFactor * sM.durabilityForce);
            scaleY -= transform.localScale.y / (strengthFactor * sM.durabilityForce);
            scaleZ -= transform.localScale.z / (strengthFactor * sM.durabilityForce);
            transform.localScale = new Vector3(scaleX, scaleY, scaleZ);
        }
    }
```

---

For example if move finger slowly object will reach his scale.x == 0.3 for 5 seconds, but if he move his finger fast enough, he will achieve this scale for 3 seconds.

Comment: So what is `sM.durabilityForce`?

Comment: It's just a variable from another script to slow down scale decreasing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should rather make the scaling depended on the [`Touch.deltaPosition`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Touch-deltaPosition.html) which is the delta the touch was moved since the last frame.

> The position delta since last change in pixel coordinates.

> The absolute position of the touch is recorded periodically and available in the `position` property. The `deltaPosition` value is a `Vector2` in **pixel coordinates** that represents the difference between the touch position recorded on the most recent update and that recorded on the previous update. The `deltaTime` value gives the time that elapsed between the previous and current updates; **you can calculate the touch's speed of motion by dividing `deltaPosition.magnitude` by `deltaTime`**.

So you could do something like e.g.

```
public float sensibility = 10;

if (Input.touchCount > 0 && canRub)
{
    Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);

    if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
    {
        var moveSpeed = Touch.deltaPosition.magnitude / Time.deltaTime;
        // since moveSpeed is still in pixel space 
        // you need to adjust the sensibility according to your needs
        var factor = strengthFactor * sM.durabilityForce * moveSpeed * sensibility;

        scaleX -= transform.localScale.x / factor;
        scaleY -= transform.localScale.y / factor;
        scaleZ -= transform.localScale.z / factor;

        transform.localScale = new Vector3(scaleX, scaleY, scaleZ);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, thank you, I find the same solution, so it should work :3